# Outputting CDATA in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, cdata

How would I, using XQuery, transform

```
<author>John Smith</author>
```

to

```
<author><![CDATA[John Smith]]></author>
```

?

Also, how would I transform

```
<content>&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Hello&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</content>
```

to

```
<content><![CDATA[<p><em>Hello</em></p>]]></content>
```

?

If it matters, I am using XSLPalette.app.

Answer (score 1):

XSLPalette seems to use Saxon under the covers, so it should support the cdata-section-elements option on xsl:output.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output for details.

Essentially, if the underlying XSLT processor supports it, you can code

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="name1 name2 ... etc"/>
```

The value of cdata-section-elements is a space-separated list of tag names for which child text nodes are to be output as CDATA sections.

I'll be curious to know if this works with XSLPalette.

Comment: Yes, that does work... with XSLT. I'm trying to achieve the same with XQuery.

Comment: The same cdata-section-elements option is available in the XQuery spec.  You'll have to determine how XSLPalette specifies XQuery serialization parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

```
declare namespace saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/";
declare option saxon:output "cdata-section-elements=content";
```

[Thanks to Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515532/outputting-cdata-in-xquery/1515592#1515592) for inspiring me to search the Saxon documentation a little more carefully.